# MSAA not in the main thread produce new behavior

Tags: multithreading, qt, com, atl

I have an issue with Microsoft Active Accessibility and threads in Qt. Code for example below:

```
CComPtr<IAccessible> _pAccMain;
HWND _hWnd = ...; // Handle of some window
HRESULT hr0 = ::AccessibleObjectFromWindow(_hWnd,
                                              OBJID_CLIENT,
                                              IID_IAccessible,
                                              (void**)(&_pAccMain));
long childCount = 0;

HRESULT hr1 = _pAccMain->get_accChildCount(&childCount);
```

It works fine and in the main-thread these functions returns success for hr0 and hr1 and I got a proper success data for _pAccMain and childCount. But when I create a new thread and try to use the code in that new thread I got again success for hr0 and hr1, but I got different data in _pAccMain and childCount. I.e. the same code have more than one behavior in different threads.

Why another thread have another behavior in that example?

How can I fix it behavior?

Can I fix it?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you calling `CoInitialize` in each thread? If you are sharing pointers between threads, are you calling `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` in each thread?

Comment: Yes, I am calling CoInitializeEx with success in a thread where I try to use msaa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Qt quietly initialized COM in each new thread and after that CoInitializeEx with any COINIT can't do anything with it. But if you call in new QThread CoUnitialize before CoInitializeEx all will be ok, it is works for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day ...!

Answer (score 1):

- There is no promise that `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` calls return the same interface pointer, so `_pAccMain` values don't have to be pointer-equal
- Additionally, calling from different threads (apartments) might have marshaling involved, in which case you might get a proxy interface, not real object interface; it is behavior by design that those are different pointers
- By mentioning different `childCount` you should have mentioned if worker thread get you zero, or otherwise what exactly is different in child enumeration
- There is no free COM pointer passing between threads in COM, what your question suggests you are doing; you can only do this with MTA threads, and otherwise you have to marshal/unmarshal pointers to get a valid pointer in another thread

Comment: I think second clause is my case and I get a proxy interface instead of a real object interface. But the proxy have only two child and I can't get needed data from application. Can I workaround this and get real object interface in not main thread?

Comment: You can get real object from the same COM apartment. However, my guess is that changed children count is not because of COM. MSDN says: ["The number of children in an object can change. An application tracks the changes to the child count by watching for `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` and `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY` events generated by this object."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318476) My guess would be this is the root of the problem.

Comment: How can it be root of issue if in a main thread all is always ok, but in others threads always is not ok? I do not understand... And I tryed all COINIT values in CoInitializeEx for new thread but it does not affect. I have not ideas how I can work properly with IAccessible _only_  not in the main thread.